# Sqlite select and join from same table and group by

Tags: python, database, sqlite, join

I have a sqlite table like below.

| bill_no | bill_date | discount | expense | total | bill_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12745 | 2022-08-30 |  |  | 200 | Normal Bill |
| 15246 | 2022-08-30 |  |  | 100 | Return Bill |
| 12345 | 2022-08-31 |  | 35 | 920 | Normal Bill |
| 56789 | 2022-08-31 | 10 |  | 310 | Normal Bill |
| 15248 | 2022-08-31 |  |  | 320 | Normal Bill |

Now I want to perform a query on this where I get sum of discount as discount, sum of expense as expense, sum of total as total using bill_type and group by.
bill_type can also have "Return Bill" value.(may or may not for the same day)
I want the output as follows.

| bill_date | discount | expense | returns | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-30 | 0 | 0 | 100 | 100 |
| 2022-08-31 | 10 | 35 | 0 | 1575 |

total in output table=total+expense-discount-returns in first table
returns in output table =sum of total where bill_type='Return Bill' for the day

If bill_type is 'Return Bill' it will not have discount, expense values

I tried following.

```
select bill_date,discount,expense,returns, total FROM 
(select bill_date, sum(discount) as discount,sum(expense) as expense,
sum(total) as total from invoice where bill_type='Normal Bill' 
and bill_date between '2022-08-30' and '2022-08-31' group by bill_date) 
JOIN 
(select bill_date, sum(total) as returns from invoice where 
bill_type='Return Bill' and bill_date 
between '2022-08-30' and '2022-08-31' group by bill_date) 
USING (bill_date);

select bill_date,discount,expense,returns, total FROM 
(select bill_date, sum(discount) as discount,sum(expense) as expense,
sum(total) as total from invoice where bill_type='Normal Bill' 
and bill_date between '2022-08-30' and '2022-08-31') 
JOIN 
(select bill_date, sum(total) as returns from invoice where 
bill_type='Return Bill' and bill_date 
between '2022-08-30' and '2022-08-31') 
USING (bill_date)  
group by bill_date;
```

This will produce some output but with groupby statement but when I add groupby statement output will disappear.
Can someone help me to have a query which produces the required output as in the 2nd table?

Comment: How is this related to python?

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT bill_date,
       TOTAL(discount) discount,
       TOTAL(expense) expense,
       TOTAL(CASE WHEN bill_type = 'Return Bill' THEN total END) returns,
       TOTAL(
         total * CASE bill_type WHEN 'Normal Bill' THEN 1 WHEN 'Return Bill' THEN -1 END +
         COALESCE(expense, 0) -
         COALESCE(discount, 0)
       ) total
FROM invoice
WHERE bill_date BETWEEN '2022-08-30' AND '2022-08-31'
GROUP BY bill_date;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=211072738ca98ad07373032b3455cb80).